# How to remove a specific history from browser, like a last login page, with JS/ jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, browser-history

I have a system, which has a login page, and after entering credentials, I have clicked on login button. After its redirecting me to my account page, I click BACK button, and I want it to be a blank page, not the login page, as I have already been logged in.

So is it possible that I can delete the last page, i.e. login page from the browser history, and at pressing back button, I can get blank page?

So my basic question is, how do I clear my latest back history (HISTORY -1)?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, unless the user has an add-on (or plug-in) installed on their browsers which is under your control.

But you can try something alternative to disable history.back(). such as `javascript:location.replace(this.href);`.

Comment: I can use location.replace() functionality on onclick() event only..so is there any other possibility, for clearing the history?

Comment: window.open will start a new history session, but I don't think it useful in your situation.